# How to add edges without changing the form ?

Tags: modeling, edges, geometry

Is it possible to add edges like in picture without affecting the smoothed geometry ? If i add in the edge ring with edge ring tool, it will deform the form but i need it to stay perfectly rounded.  [image]

Comment: Please explain more in depth. What do you mean with smoothed geometry (a subdivision surface modifier)?

Comment: I basically need to add  edges vertically(where the line is) without changing the roundness

Answer (score 3):

Use ***To Sphere*** tool. After adding the vertical *loop cuts* select each loop with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, change the *pivot type* to *Individual Origins*, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and drag the cursor outwards the mesh. Select the other loop and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the process. Do the same with the other ones. Now you've got additional loops in your mesh and it's also perfectly smooth.
[image]

***EDIT:*** If you need to add the horizontal loopcuts also you may subdivide your mesh (<kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide*), then smooth the vertices (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>-->*Smooth Vertex*) and increse the *Smoothing* value to *1.000*. As you can see the objects look the same.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for very informative answer. That is how to add edge loops horizontally, but what about adding them vertically? I tried with spherizing tool but it deformed top and bottom of my mesh. But i had only selected one loop. would it work with all loops selected.That way is not good for that reason. Is there another way without using smooth modifier?

Comment: Thank you a thousand times ! That's what ive been looking for.